# jQuery event handling with .live() problem with setInterval and clearInterval

Tags: jquery, event-handling, live, setinterval

jQuery 1.4.2:

I have an image. When the mouseover event is triggered, a function is executed that runs a loop to load several images. On the contrary, the mouseout event needs to set the image back to a predetermined image and no longer have the loop executing. These are only for the images with class "thumb":

```
$("img.thumb").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
    //var foo = $(this).attr('id');
    var wait;
    var i=0;
    var image = document.getElementById(foo);

    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
        function incrementimage()
        {
            i++;
            image.src = 'http://example.com/images/file_'+i+'.jpg';
            if(i==30) {i=0;}
        }    
        wait = setInterval(incrementimage,500);
    } else if (event.type == 'mouseout') {
        clearInterval (wait);
        image.src = 'http://example.com/images/default.jpg';
    }
    return false;
});
```

When I mouseout, the image is set to the default.jpg but the browser continues to loop though the images. It will never stop. Can someone hit me with some knowledge? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the mouseout event doesn't see the same `wait` that the mouseover event did. You need to store it somewhere else. I would suggest using [`data()][1]` to store it on the element.

Also, this sequence doesn't make sense:

```
var foo = $(this).attr('id');
...
var image = document.getElementById(foo);
```

`this` is already the image element.

Lastly, that's not how I'd define the function. Try something like:

```
$("img.thumb").live("mouseover", function(evt) {
  var wait = $(this).data("wait");
  if (!wait) {
    clearInterval(wait);
  }
  var i = 0;
  var image = this;
  var incrementImage = function() {
    i++;
    image.src = "http://example.com/images/file_" + i + ".jpg";
    if (i == 30) {
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  wait = setInterval(incrementImage, 500);
  $(this).data("wait", wait);
  return false;
});

$("img.thumb").live("mouseout", function(event) {
  var wait = $(this).data("wait");
  if (wait) {
    clearInterval(wait);
  }
  img.src = "http://example.com/default.jpg";
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can shorten your code down to this to clear the interval properly:

```
$("img.thumb").live("mouseover", function() {
  var i = 0, image = this, incrementimage = function() {
    i++;
    image.src = 'http://example.com/images/file_'+i+'.jpg';
    if(i==30) {i=0;}
  };
  $(this).data('timer', setInterval(incrementimage,500));
}).live("mouseout", function() {
  clearInterval($(this).data('timer'));
  this.src = 'http://example.com/images/default.jpg';
});
```

This splits the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) calls to make the logic a bit cleaner, and stores the previous `wait` id on the element itself using [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried moving your `var wait` outside your .live() event?

```
var wait
$("img.thumb").live("mouseover mouseout", function(event) {
```